# Remove padding around HTML5 video element

Tags: css, html, video

I'm putting a video above a 750px width column of content but there's some padding around the video I can't get rid of. The original dimenions of the video are 1280px width so it's not a case of the video being too small.

[image]

I want the video to extend to the edges of the content (i.e. to fill the 750px space). Here's my HTML

```
    <video width="100%" height="350" controls>
       <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/vid/linecatching.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your video was 1280px wide,  I am going to guess its 720px tall.  In your HTML code you have

```
height="350"
```

Try setting the width to the 750px,and don't set the height at all.

Comment: try  this: video{padding:0 !important;}

Comment: Nick, you've nailed it. Thanks mate, new to video production and wasn't sure how it faired on the web. Correct answer, will accept when time has passed.

Comment: Hey I was facing the same issue, but my video's dimensions are 3840x2160. I didn't set the height and padding was removed, but now the height is too tall for my page. Can you please tell me how can I fix this?